# How to find the nearest single point?

Tags: qgis, point

I have two shapefiles containing each one set of points, set A and set B. One set is my random selection (set A), the other is a list of communities (set B).

For each point of the random selection (set A) I want to find the nearest point pertaining to

Comment: is your set B a list of centroids?

Answer (score 3):

You could use GRASS' [v.distance](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.distance.html) via the [Sextante plugin](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Sextante). It calculates all these distances.

Answer (score 0):

The *GRASS* *v.distance* function should do the job, but it does not work through QGIS *Processing*.  It can, however, be used through the QGIS *GRASS* plugin.

Other easily available alternatives in QGIS are *Distance matrix* (under Vector-> Analysis Tools) and the *NNJoin* plugin.